# Where do I start with a changing homepage?

Tags: php, html

I'm building a website with a homepage that has a different article everyday. I know how to change it using html, but that requires daily maintenance. Is there anyway I can change a picture and text daily without changing code everyday? I'd also like to be able to see the previous days' article by using an 'older' button or something.
I'm not asking for the whole code by the way, just for someone to point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Gave you +3 rep points, this site is hard to use without rep points. Best of luck with your site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/).

Comment: Different article every day... older button... Yep, sounds like a blog to me. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

How about a Content Management System like [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)?  If you're just doing static content updates, that may work well for you

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking into that now.

Comment: @Jake: Based on the specs you gave, Wordpress is this choice, not Joomla. Wordpress is the most common CMS (content management system) -- but it's designed for blogs, which is the formatted you outlined; meaning "web" based content is "log"ged in reverse chronology; weblog = blog.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to utilize CMS to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make this by adding the article and images into the database. or images in the folder.

You can google for better article for doing this.or you can use cms e.g. joomla , wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the info, are these the only methods of doing this. I mean as in what do all the big websites use to replace front page articles?

Comment: @Jake All site store the data in database and retrieve them. the changing html is not good approach for managing every day data.